# 2019 Kia Sorento annoying and now dangerous electrical issues

Tags: electrical, kia, sorento

I had a 2013 and a 2016 Sorento and they always worked perfectly. Now I have a 2019 and have had annoying electrical issues from nearly the start, and today something very dangerous happened.

The annoying issues are things like the heat setting just changing itself for no apparent reason, or random "battery discharge" warnings. I've had the car into the shop a few times, and they always claim they can't reproduce the problem. Because these are merely annoying, I've just let it go.

Today, however, my wife was driving on the interstate when the car lost all power and switched itself into neutral. She was able to coast to a safe stop, and then switch into Park. The car was fine the rest of the day, but now we're afraid to drive the thing.

I'm also expecting that the dealer is going to say they can't find anything wrong and we'll be in the position of having a car that we don't feel safe driving, but can't get fixed.

What do we do in a situation like this?

Comment: Your first resource here is the dealer but you should keep ALL the paperwork.  Check with your state or province for "lemon laws", if the car has problems which cannot be resolved, they may be required to buy it back from you.

Comment: What happens if they just claim there IS no problem, because it doesn't happen when they try it (for probably 10 minutes) when I bring it in? That's what they've been doing for a year with the minor issues.

Comment: You might want to document every incident. Take pictures, write down what ,when and where faults occurred. Your owners manual will have contact information on who to contact to escalate a problem.

Comment: You need to document everything.  Dates, times, symptoms, dangerous situations, take photos.  Imagine what you might need if you went to court and had to present a case.  Yes, these things are very frustrating but there is a lot at stake for you.

Comment: Dealers have an overall bad reputation, for a good reason, but they aren't all bad. You lose nothing by trying, chances are good they will fix the problem under warranty.